# OS X Save menu item is disabled

Tags: macos, nsmenuitem

I am implementing the save item menu for my app. I made this method: `- (IBAction)saveDocument:(id)sender`. But the save menu item of my app is disabled. I also checked the storyboard to make sure the enabled is checked. It is still disabled. How do you fix it.

Comment: Did you set the target and action for the menu item?

Comment: @rocky I did make sure the action is set to `saveDocument` action.

Comment: Are you using Automatic Menu Enabling or Manual Menu Enabling?